# Any way to do one-to-many association by non primary key in JPA-hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I am trying to do one to many association by a non primary key of the parent. I am using JPA 2.1 with hibernate. I have found several similar questions. But i think my case is a bit different.

I have two table :
`ProfileBasic` and `Phonenumber`.

```
    @Entity
public class ProfileBasic {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       @Column(name = "profile_id")
       private Long id;     
       
       //....some columns.
       
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
        private List<PhoneNumber> phone_number;

        // getters-setters
}


public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // getters-setters and other columns
    
}
```

Database tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `profilebasic` (
  `profile_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `available` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blood_Group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `care_of` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marital_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profession` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `religion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for table `profilebasic`
--
ALTER TABLE `profilebasic`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`);


    CREATE TABLE `phonenumber` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for table `phonenumber`
--
ALTER TABLE `phonenumber`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `FK8sfxu3ejjpklkd3njt3767ape` (`profile_id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `phonenumber`
--
ALTER TABLE `phonenumber`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK8sfxu3ejjpklkd3njt3767ape` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profilebasic` (`profile_id`);
```

I have other tables and have made several `views` from those tables, where some cases `profile_id` is the `Primary Key` on those view. I have done successfully `one to many` association from `views`, where primary key is `profile_id`. But i have a view, where `profile_id` is not PK, as a result in time of fetching, it is generating right query but with wrong value.

```
Hibernate: select phone_numb0_.profile_id as profile_3_18_0_, phone_numb0_.id as id1_18_0_, phone_numb0_.id as id1_18_1_, phone_numb0_.number as number2_18_1_ from PhoneNumber phone_numb0_ where phone_numb0_.profile_id=?
2020-08-23 04:00:48.396 TRACE 9292 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [21451]
```

Here `parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [21451]` is the wrong value : PK of the `view`, where right value will be `1134`. But as i told earlier, this is working where the primary key of the view is `profile_id`.

I have seen several questions in `stackoverflow`. Now i want to know : is there any way by which i can associate the `phone number` by `one-to-many`, where `profile_id` is not PK. If it is not possible, i have to read the phone number for each row of the `views`.

View Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "donner_assing_show")
public class DonnerAssingShow implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "donner_assingment_id")
    private long donnerAssingmentId;


    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "agent_id")
    private String agentId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "donner_id")
    private String donnerId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "assing_date")
    private String assingDate;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "assing_note")
    private String assingNote;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "need_date")
    private String needDate;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private String postId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "blood_manage_status")
    private String bloodManageStatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    private long profileId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "available")
    private String available;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private String birthDate;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "blood_Group")
    private String bloodGroup;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "care_of")
    private String careOf;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "marital_status")
    private String maritalStatus;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "religion")
    private String religion;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany
    //    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phone_number;

    //    @OneToMany
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private List<Address> addressList;

    // constructor-getter/setters
}
```

[GitHub Link of the project where stacked](https://github.com/ajharulabedeen/com.donatedrop/tree/dev/back_end/com.donatedrop/src/main/java/com/donatedrop/agent/donner)

[Unit Test of the code](https://github.com/ajharulabedeen/com.donatedrop/blob/dev/back_end/com.donatedrop/src/test/java/com/donatedrop/agent/doner/Test_Dao_DonnerAssign_Impl.java)

[Dump Data of the project](https://github.com/ajharulabedeen/com.donatedrop/blob/dev/files/drop_new_22_08_2020.sql)

Answer (score 0):

The join column is not required to be part of the primary key, or using the same column name in both tables. You can specify which column you want to join by using "referenceColumnName".

```
@Entity
public class ProfileBasic 
{
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       @Column(name = "profile_id")
       private Long id;     
       
       //....some columns.
       
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile", orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<PhoneNumber> phone_number;

        // getters-setters
}
```

```
public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable 
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName = "profile_id", nullable = false)
    private ProfileBasic profile;
    
    // getters-setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class ProfileBasic {
       
   //....some columns.
   
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable {

    // getters-setters and other columns
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", nullable = false)
    private ProfileBasic profile;
}
```

Comments:

1. The `@JoinColumn` annotation should be used on side that owns foreign key column (this is `PhoneNumber` in your case).
2. It is not necessary to use the `referencedColumnName` when the FK refereed to the PK column.
3. It is good to follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). So, it is better to use `phoneNumbers` as a property name instead of `phone_number`.